# Eigen3 library with C++20 format

Tags: c++, c++20, eigen3

I am trying to print Eigen::Array or Eigen::Matrix with c++20 format, instead of Eigen::IOFormat.
I would like to control the precision and alignment of elements in the matrix with specifiers, for example,

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Eigen::ArrayXXd mat( 3, 4 );
    mat.setZero();
    std::cout << std::format( "mat={:9.4f}\n", mat );
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the following expected result?

```
mat=   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
       0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
       0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/extend-std-format-in-c-20-for-user-defined-types.
I'm sure you will be able to apply this to `Eigen` types.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at https://gite.lirmm.fr/rpc/utils/eigen-fmt and see if it helps you out.

You basically need to include [this header file](https://gite.lirmm.fr/rpc/utils/eigen-fmt/-/blob/master/include/eigen-fmt/eigen-fmt/fmt.h) in order to have eigen support for print/format using the `fmt` library. Since `std::format` was based from `fmt`, that code should be a good start in order to achieve what you want. Note that you may need to make a few adjustments.